# Install webapplication in a new web site?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, installation, setup-project

How do I install a web application as a web site in IIS6 using the regular Web Setup Project? I do not want to install the application as a virtual directory in "Default Web Site", but a new web site (and if possible create the site during the installation).

Also, is it possible to select the ASP.Net 4 Application pool as default in the setup wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.